# Dispatch a scroll event from listview to scrollview

Tags: android, listview, scrollview, touch-event

I have a ListView in which every row contains the following

```
-2 images
-1 textview
-1 scrollview that will display a bunch of tags
```

I searched the internet and I found out that is really hard to dispatch the scroll event from a listview to it's children, especially when they scroll on the same axis.

I was thinking if there is a possibility to find out if the touch event was on the scrollview and if it is, then I should dispatch the scroll event, else I will scroll the list.

Do you have any ideas how can I implement that?

EDIT:

I tried to to override the onTouchEvent method from the ListView but It doesn't work. When I drag over the scroll view the content disappears and when I scroll the listview, the content of the scroll view remains smudged on the screen.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you find a solution? I'm kinda facing the same problem